# Do horcrux effects come into play before or after abilities?

Tags: turn-order, harry-potter-hogwarts-battle

After resolving the dark arts cards and villain effects, my character has 1hp. That same character has the "potions" proficiency, so if he plays a spell, ally, and item, any hero gains a hp and a zap.

My character does indeed have all three types of cards in his hand and will be playing all of them. However, the "diary" horcrux is still in play, which says "Each time a Hero plays an Ally, that Hero loses 1hp."

Does the horcrux effect come into play before my character's special ability? In other words, is my character stunned or do I survive this with 1hp? We are thinking that I am stunned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my [previous answer regarding the situation](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/a/45141/14751), I don't think you can avoid the stun by gaining the heart. As soon as you play an ally the horcrux would trigger, causing the stun to happen and stunning states:

> You cannot lose (**or gain**) [heath] any more this turn.

Then the card effects would happen. Here's a BoardGameGeek thread discussing this exact situation:

https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/1677572/diary-affect-timing