# If I play a card and playing that card stuns me, do I get to use the effect of the card still?

Tags: turn-order, harry-potter-hogwarts-battle

Currently the "Diary" horcrux is active which says "Each time a Hero plays an Ally, that Hero loses 1hp."

My hero is currently at 1hp and has an ally to play. That ally gives me a zap to use. When I play the ally and obtain the zap, do I get to use it against a villain or is it removed by me getting stunned? Our players are currently divided about the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I interpret the rules is that you can use the zap. Here's what the rulebook says when being stunned:

> Discard any or tokens you may have saved on your Player Board
>   **from other Heroes’ turns**.
> If it is your turn, **you may still play cards and take actions** with whatever you have remaining after being Stunned.

The above was found on page 18 of the rulebook regarding Hero Health. [View PDF Rulebook](https://theop.games/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/Harry-Potter-DB-G1-Rules.pdf)

I would assume that the stun happens immediately and you would follow the stunned steps from top to bottom.